# Django Mongoengine concurrent saves are failing

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a web API running on Django using Mongoengine which does the following

```
print "Saving", data
modelObj.dataList.append(data)
modelObj.save()
```

I also have an API that calls this function in a pretty tight loop which results in the following log:

```
Saving {'answer': u'3'}
[25/Apr/2013 17:12:00] "POST /submit HTTP/1.1" 200 10
Saving {'answer': u'2'}
Saving {Saving {'answer': u'5'}}
[25/Apr/2013 17:12:00] "POST /submit HTTP/1.1" 200 30
[25/Apr/2013 17:12:00] "POST /submit HTTP/1.1" 200 30
[25/Apr/2013 17:12:00] "POST /submit HTTP/1.1" 200 10
Saving {'answer': u'1'}
[25/Apr/2013 17:12:00] "POST /submit HTTP/1.1" 200 10
```

Clearly, the saves are happening concurrently. The output is that I am rarely seeing all 5 results being written to the database. Is there something really fundamental I am overlooking here?

UPDATE: Using Mongoengine 0.7.9. Docs state:

```
Changed in version 0.5: In existing documents it only saves changed fields using  
set / unset. Saves are cascaded and any DBRef objects that have changes are saved as well.
```

Not sure if this disproves my theory...

Comment: Churning through the logic, if I pull out a modelObj (A) any operations on that modelObj by other concurrent methods will not be reflected. Presumably calling 'save' is an absolute operation rather than an addition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saves in mongoengine are atomic, however, when saving a list it does it as a `$set` for the ***whole list***.  So you could have a race condition.

This is why the preferred way to append to a list is to do a `$push` eg:

```
modelObj.update(push__dataList=data)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Nice to get a comment from the maintainer :) Out of curiosity, how would this look if my list we actually being appended to another list? I simplified the example but it looks like this `modelObj.dataList[index].append(data)` where index is the same value in my concurrent example.

Answer (score 0):

table_name.objects.filter(__id=1).update(push__fieldname={'key' : 'value','key' : 'value',}) if you want delete than pull